# How to use "if statement" in a formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

| Amount | Payment model |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Yearly |
| 6 | Monthly |

In the 3rd column, I wish to introduce a formula which will automatically read the entry in column "Payment Model".
If the entry is, "Yearly" it will just copy the value from column "Amount".
If the entry is, "Monthly" it will multiply the value with 12.

Thanks in advance

Tried using the "if" statement, its not working.
Here is my formula: `=IF($B2 == "Yearly",$A2*1,$A2*12)`

Throws me a Formula error everytime.

Comment: Excel does not use `==`: `=IF($B2="Yearly",1,12)*$A2`

Comment: Only once `=` then the formula will be `=IF($B2="Yearly",$A2*1,$A2*12)`

Comment: Where does PowerPoint come into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not use the double equals.
The formula you want, provided by [Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889736/if-statement-formula#comment132161607_74889736) and [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889736/if-statement-formula#comment132161594_74889736):

```
=IF($B2="Yearly",$A2*1,$A2*12)
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer, as this is correct. Yet, I would use the distributivity of multiplication and have a since multiplication in the formula and the `IF` would only determine what to multiply with, for better readability.

Comment: And a quick internet search for "excel if" brought up some surprisingly clear & helpful documentation from MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
=$A2 * IF($B2="Monthly", 12, 1)
```

We need `$A2` anyway and we use the `IF` to determine what to multiply it with. Note that the comparison is done via the `=` operator.

[image]